# System.IO.File.Copy Error with file not found

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a image upload that can copy the image into a folder. The problem is that when I try to copy the photo to a folder, there is an error which says that it could not find the file. My code is below:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //
            // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
            // We print the number of files found.
            //
            string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

        }

        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

            //001: Check the user selected a file and pressed ok button. Before opening the dialog
            //      set the filters
            dlgFileOpen.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp";

            string path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            if (dlgFileOpen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               // string file = Path.GetFileName(dlgFileOpen.FileName);
                string file = Path.GetFileName(dlgFileOpen.FileName);
                //string file2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(file, Path.GetFileName(dlgFileOpen.FileName));
                string newFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, file);
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, newFileName, true);


                //image directory to be saved in database
                //txtSelectedFile.Text = newFileName;
            }
        }


    private void dlgFileOpen_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string Required_Ext = ".jpeg .jpg .bmp";
        string selected_ext = Path.GetExtension(dlgFileOpen.FileName);
        int index = Required_Ext.IndexOf(selected_ext);
        //002: Inform the user to select correct extension
        if (index < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Extension Maaaan... Extension! Open only jpeg or bmp or jpg");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

ANSWER:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //
            // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
            // We print the number of files found.
            //
            string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

        }

        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

            //001: Check the user selected a file and pressed ok button. Before opening the dialog
            //      set the filters
            dlgFileOpen.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp";

            string path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            if (dlgFileOpen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               // string file = Path.GetFileName(dlgFileOpen.FileName);
                string file = Path.GetFileName(dlgFileOpen.FileName);
                //string file2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(file, Path.GetFileName(dlgFileOpen.FileName));
                string newFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, file);
                System.IO.File.Copy(dlgFileOpen.FileName, newFileName, true);

                txtSelectedFile.Text = newFileName;
                MessageBox.Show("Image uploaded successful!");
            }
        }


    private void dlgFileOpen_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string Required_Ext = ".jpeg .jpg .bmp";
        string selected_ext = Path.GetExtension(dlgFileOpen.FileName);
        int index = Required_Ext.IndexOf(selected_ext, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        //002: Inform the user to select correct extension
        if (index < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Extension Maaaan... Extension! Open only jpeg or bmp or jpg");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you found the answer, you should post an answer - don't edit it into the question. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're losing the full file path on the source file.

```
string file = Path.GetFileName(dlgFileOpen.FileName);  // "file" is the file name
string newFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, file);
System.IO.File.Copy(file, newFileName, true);
```

Replace this:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(file, newFileName, true);
```

With this:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(dlgFileOpen.FileName, newFileName, true);
```

Regarding your other issue, from the comments:

> "Even though i set the filer with jpeg, how come 1 picture of mine which is jpeg will trigger my error message?"

It's most likely a case-sensitivity issue. Your code will only allow lower-case file extensions; if the file you select is ".JPEG" (all uppercase) it will fail and display the error message.

You can ignore case by calling the overloaded method that accepts a `StringComparison` type:

```
int index = Required_Ext.IndexOf(
                selected_ext, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: indeed, this is the problem. File.Copy requires full path of the file and Path.GetFileName returns only file name with extension.

Comment: I have 1 more question though, even though i set the filer with jpeg, how come 1 picture of mine which is jpeg will trigger my error message?

Comment: Okay that worked out nicely thanks alot for all the help :D. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh that's nice :D thanks alot! 1st time i am using ask a question function on stackoverflow didn't expect it to work out so well.